# Show that the following sequence is a cauchy sequence $a_n=\frac{10}{1}+ \frac{11}{3} +... + \frac{10+n}{2n+1}$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the following sequence is a cauchy sequence
$a_n=\frac{10}{1}+ \frac{11}{3} +... + \frac{10+n}{2n+1}$

what I tried:

We know that a sequence $(a_n)$ is Cauchy if for every positive real number $\varepsilon$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that for all $m,n>N$, $|a_m-a_n|<\varepsilon$.

$|a_{n+p}-a_n|=|(\frac{10}{1}+ \frac{11}{3} +... + \frac{10+n}{2n+1}+\frac{10+(n+1)}{2(n+1)+1}+ ... + \frac{10+(n+p)}{2(n+p)+1})-(\frac{10}{1}+ \frac{11}{3} +... + \frac{10+n}{2n+1})|$

$=(\frac{10+(n+1)}{2(n+1)+1}+\frac{10+(n+2)}{2(n+2)+1}+ ... + \frac{10+(n+p)}{2(n+p)+1})$

$<(\frac{10+(n+1)}{n+1}+\frac{10+(n+2)}{(n+2)}+ ... + \frac{10+(n+p)}{(n+p)})$

$=\frac{10}{n+1}+1+\frac{10}{n+2}+1+ ... + \frac{10}{n+p} +10$

$=p+ \frac{10}{n+1} + \frac{10}{n+2} + ... + \frac{10}{n+p}+1$

$=p + \frac{10}{n+1} + ... + \frac{10}{n+p}$

$<p + \frac{10}{n} + ... + \frac{10}{n}$

$=p + \frac{10p}{n}$

I am not usre that this is possible but if $p=2N$ and we know that $n>N$ then

$<p (1+ \frac{10}{N})$

$<2N+20$

and from here we can choose $N= \lceil \frac{\varepsilon -20}{2} \rceil$

I am not sure of what I did and if that actually proves that it is a cauchy sequence so any tips and help is appreciated!

If a series is divergent does it mean it is not cauchy? is there a difference if talking about series or sequence in cauchy sequence related topic?

Comment: Your sequence is not a Cauchy sequence. $\sum \frac {10+n}{2n+1}$ is a divergent series because the general term tends to $\frac 1 2\neq 0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I am a bit confused, if I look at it as a series it is divergent but if I take the general element then the limit of the sequence is $\frac{1}{2}$ which is convergent.

Comment: Yes, $\sum \frac 1 n$ is divergent even though the general term $\frac 1 n$ tends to $0$. That is not a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to verify directly that the sequence is not Cauchy, you can look at the difference of each term with the following term:
$$a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{10+(n+1)}{2(n+1)+1} = \frac{n+11}{2n+3}
$$
Notice that the limit of this sequence is $\frac{1}{2}$. So if you pick $\epsilon = \frac{1}{4}$ then you are guaranteed that there exists $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$ we have $\left| \frac{n+11}{2n+3} - \frac{1}{2} \right| < \frac{1}{4}$, and therefore
$$\left| \frac{n+11}{2n+3} \right|  > \frac{1}{4}
$$

Now we can argue by contradiction that if this sequence ***is*** Cauchy, then there exists $M$ such that if $k,l \ge M$ then $|a_k-a_l| < \frac{1}{4}$. Taking $n = k = \text{max}\{M,N\}$ and $l=k+1$ we obtain a contradiction:
$$\left| \frac{n+11}{2n+3} \right|  < \frac{1}{4}
$$

---

This strategy generalizes: if you have a sequence $a_n$ such that $a_{n+1}-a_n$ converges to a nonzero number (which popped out at me right away when looking at the sequence in your post), then the sequence is not Cauchy.

Comment: To clarify one point, $$a_{n+1} = \underbrace{\frac{10}{1} + \frac{11}{3} + ... + \frac{10+n}{2n+1}}_{a_n} + \frac{10+(n+1)}{2(n+1)+1}$$

Comment: thank you I noticed this just a minute before you posted :) thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Define $ b_k = \frac{10 + k}{2k +1} $, then we have $ a_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n b_k $. We will show that $(a_n)_n$ is **not** a Cauchy sequence i.e. there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for all $N  \in \mathbb{N}$, there exist $m, n > N$ such that $|a_m - a_n| \geq \varepsilon$.

Since $ \lim_{k \to \infty} b_k = 1/2 $, if we let $\delta = 1/4$, there exists some $ D \in \mathbb{N}$ such that when $k > D$, $ |b_k - 1/2| < \delta $, thus $ |b_k - 1/2| < 1/4 $ and hence $ b_k > 1/4$. We will use this to show that $(a_n)_n$ is not Cauchy.

Now, fix $ \varepsilon = 1/4$, and let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. Choose $n = \max(D, N) + 1$, and set $m = n + 1$. Then $m > n > N$, and we compute that $ |a_m - a_n| = |a_m - a_{m - 1}| = | \sum_{k = 0}^m b_k - \sum_{k = 0}^{m-1} b_k | = |b_m| > 1/4 = \varepsilon $, where the second last inequality follows from what we proved earlier since $m > D$.